# How to PHP String Obfuscation on Decrypt

Tags: php, variables, obfuscation

I saw that the lines in a file in my hand. I encoded variables. How can I resolve these variables? Example : $GLOBALS['whsuotvkj'] ?, $GLOBALS['nmbkoryi'] ?

```
 $ekzhioy = "do".__FILE__;
$yhburqp = "do".__FILE__;
$GLOBALS['whsuotvkj'] = "bol";
$ctkebbxxi = "do".__FILE__;
$sgacjqhdl = "bol";
$ctkebbxxi = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$GLOBALS['feqpjcoo'] = explode( ".", $yhburqp );
$GLOBALS['nmbkoryi'] = "bol";
if ( is_numeric( $GLOBALS['whsuotvkj'][0] ) && is_numeric( $sgacjqhdl[1] ) )
{
    return $ekzhioy;
}
```

Comment: There's no automatism for deducing original variable names and intend. Obfuscation is typically a one-way ticket.

Answer (score 0):

As mario commented, the point of obfuscation is to make it extremely difficult for people to steal code.  Respect that the original author didn't want you to see his/her code, and leave it at that.

(And if you ARE the original author and have done this by accident-- sorry!  Keep backups next time!)